misplaced item on Frame and Root
I am building an tkinter application with 2 frames inside my root. Here is my code and what I obtain:
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
root.geometry('880x600')
root.config(bg="blue")
root.resizable(0,0)

################ RIGHT FRAME ########################################
right_frame=Frame(root, width= 230, height=500, borderwidth=5, relief=GROOVE)
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)


################ RIGHT FRAME ########################################
left_frame=Frame(root, width=600, height=500, borderwidth= 5, relief= GROOVE)
left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)


sending_To= Label(root, text= 'To: ')
sending_To.grid(row=0, column=0)
sending_Textbox=Entry(root, width=15)
sending_Textbox.grid(row=0,column=0)

copy= Label(root, text= 'Cc: ')
copy.grid(row=1, column=0)
copy_Textbox=Entry(root, width=15)
copy_Textbox.grid(row=1, column=0)

subject= Label(root, text= 'Subject: ')
subject.grid(row=2, column=0)
subject_Textbox=Entry(root, width=15)
subject_Textbox.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()

Here is the result:

This is close from my intended results. However, I do not have the labels nor the 3 entries on the top left of my left frame. When I change the location of my labels and put them all in left-frame, like this:
 from tkinter import*
 from tkinter import ttk


 root = Tk()
 root.geometry('880x600')
 root.config(bg="blue")
 root.resizable(0,0)

 ################ RIGHT FRAME ########################################
 right_frame=Frame(root, width= 230, height=500, borderwidth=5, relief=GROOVE)
 right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)


 ################ RIGHT FRAME ########################################
 left_frame=Frame(root, width=600, height=500, borderwidth= 5, relief= GROOVE)
 left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)


sending_To= Label(left_frame, text= 'To: ')
sending_To.grid(row=0, column=0)
sending_Textbox=Entry(root, width=15)
sending_Textbox.grid(row=0,column=0)

copy= Label(left_frame, text= 'Cc: ')
copy.grid(row=1, column=0)
copy_Textbox=Entry(root, width=15)
copy_Textbox.grid(row=1, column=0)

subject= Label(left_frame, text= 'Subject: ')
subject.grid(row=2, column=0)
subject_Textbox=Entry(root, width=15)
subject_Textbox.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()

This is what I get:

How would put my labels next to my entries on my left frame without disrupting the whole thing. I tried many things over the weekend it seems like my both of my frames are on row 1;

You are putting multiple widgets in the same row and column. Give them different rows and/or columns.

Comment from jasonharper in your another question has already told you how to do it.

@BryanOakley How would I get my labels  and the entries on the left frame since the left frame is already on first row? is there a way to position them on the frame, using some kind x y coordinate?

The rows and columns inside each frame or window are independent. Row 0 in the left frame is not the same as row 0 in the window.

@acw1668 thank you that helped. i hope to put the solution back myself in a bit

You not paying attention for row and column for grid layout geometry.
On line 17, change sticky for left_frame.grid
Change the root to left_frame for Entry and Label widget.
Snippet:
left_frame=Frame(root, width=600, height=500, borderwidth= 5, relief='groove')
left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n') # Add sticky


sending_To= Label(left_frame, text= 'To: ')
sending_To.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
sending_Textbox=Entry(left_frame,bg='red',  width=15)
sending_Textbox.grid(row=0,column=1)

copy= Label(left_frame, text= 'Cc: ')
copy.grid(row=1, column=0)
copy_Textbox=Entry(left_frame, width=15)
copy_Textbox.grid(row=1, column=1)

subject= Label(left_frame, text= 'Subject: ')
subject.grid(row=2, column=0)
subject_Textbox=Entry(left_frame, width=15)
subject_Textbox.grid(row=2, column=1) 

May I ask. What is the second frame do?
Screenshot:

